# Pop a View when click the StatusBar Item

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

I expect to present a View when click the StatusBar Item like this:[image]

And I have set up the StatusItem

```
import Cocoa

@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {


    @IBOutlet weak var imageManager: NSMenu!

    let statusItem = NSStatusBar.systemStatusBar().statusItemWithLength(-1)



    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification) {
        let icon = NSImage(named: "statusIcon")
        icon?.template = true

        statusItem.image = icon
        statusItem.menu = imageManager
        statusItem.action = nil
    }
```

What should I do next?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest approach would be to create a NSPopover object and attach it to the status item. There are multiple tutorials online for this. [Here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/98178/os-x-tutorial-menus-popovers-menu-bar-apps) is a good one!

Although, if you need a more custom appearance, you need to write your own. For this you will need a borderless window with transparent background. Its contentView will draw the frame of the speech-bubble ish design..